# How does one make collisions for sprites in pygame?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make collisions for my basic 2D game using pygame. I've run into an issue where the game won't start and i'm getting an error.

```
     playercolidecheck = MyPlayer.collide(v)
     File "C:\Users\marti\Desktop\Python\PyMine\PyMineFile.py", line 53, 
     in collide
     return pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, enemies)
     File "C:\Users\marti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
     packages\pygame\sprite.py", line 1586, in spritecollideany
     spritecollide = sprite.rect.colliderect
     AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

I have tried to to make my own custom collision but to no avail. Here is the code for the project:

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("PyMine")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Images
dirtimage = pygame.image.load("dirt.png")
grassimage = pygame.image.load("grass.png")
woodimage = pygame.image.load("wood.png")
playerimage = pygame.image.load("player.png")

pygame.display.set_icon(grassimage)

drawlist = []

class Block:
    def __init__(self,ID,x,y,add,w,h):
        self.ID = ID
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        if add == True:
            drawlist.append(self)

    def main(self):
        if self.ID == 0:
            win.blit(dirtimage, (self.x,self.y))
        if self.ID == 1:
            win.blit(grassimage, (self.x,self.y))
        if self.ID == 2:
            win.blit(woodimage, (self.x,self.y))

class Player:
    def __init__(self,add,x,y,):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        if add == True:
            drawlist.append(self)

    def main(self):
        win.blit(playerimage, (self.x,self.y))

    def DONTUSE(self,TargetX,TargetY):
        if TargetX > self.x or TargetX < self.x or TargetY > self.y or TargetY < self.y: return False
        return True

    def collide(self, enemies):
        return pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, enemies)

MyBlock1 = Block(0,160,160,True,32,32)
MyBlock2 = Block(1,32,0,True,32,32)
MyBlock3 = Block(2,64,0,True,32,32)
MyPlayer = Player(False,96,0)

run = True
while run:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                MyPlayer.x -= 32
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                MyPlayer.x += 32
    win.fill((255,255,255))
    MyPlayer.main()
    for v in drawlist:
        v.main()
        playercolidecheck = MyPlayer.collide(v)
        if playercolidecheck == True:
            MyPlayer.y -= 0.1
            pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,25,25),[MyPlayer.x,MyPlayer.y,16,16])
    MyPlayer.y += 0.1
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

It gives me an error and it doesn't display anything on the screen. Altough it opens a window and names it and gives it its icon.

Comment: Also note that your question is longer than it needs to be.  I am certain you could remove most of the lines of code and still get this same error.  It helps us figure things out and even helps you solve more problems on your own if you break down the problem to the minimum version that will produce your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Player` class does not have a pygame `rect` object, which is required for the `spritecollideany` function.  So passing `self` into this line:

`return pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self, enemies)`

You are passing your own custom class `Player` to the function, you need to add a `rect` object to your class so `pygame` knows where it is.

So instead of using `self.x` `self.y` for player you should have a `self.rect` initialized at the start and use `self.rect.x`, `self.rect.y` for those variables.  Making sure to update this `rect` as your player moves.  This puts things in a format that `pygame` understands.